# How to enter the path of file on unix using Java

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to pass a file to `JSON` parser on the unix box like this:

```
JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse("/opt/Scheherazade/hegrid.git/hegrid-web/EventsJson.json");
```

This will run on the unix box. But I get the following error :

> Unexpected character (/) at position 0.
>           at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
>           at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)
>           at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ca.service.ModifyEventJsonFile.replaceActorJsonFile(ModifyEventJsonFile.java:21)
>           at com.ca.controller.ChefController.saveSchzScript(ChefController.java:139)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

How to enter the path correctly?

Comment: I suspect that `parse.parse(String)` assumes that the `String` is a JSON `String`, not a file reference, try `parser.parse(new File("/opt/Scheherazade/hegrid.git/hegrid-web/EventsJson.json"));` instead

Comment: I cannot use parser.parse(new File("/opt/Scheherazade/hegrid.git/hegrid-web/EventsJson.json")). parser.parse accepts a string so I have to make it as " parser.parse(String.valueOf(new File("/opt/Scheherazade/hegrid.git/hegrid-web/EventsJson.json")));"

Comment: What parser did you use?

Comment: No, sorry, you're required to provide `Reader`, had to dig the source out...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the examples found [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) and the source code, `JSONParser#parse(String)` expects the `String` value to be a JSON `String` and not a file reference.

The only only other method available is `JSONParser#parse(Reader)`, something like

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("/opt/Scheherazade/hegrid.git/hegrid-web/EventsJson.json"))) {
    JSONArray a = (JSONArray)parser.parse(reader);
}
```

should get a little closer to your goal